# Sencha Touch also for desktop?

Tags: web-applications, sencha-touch

My question is prety stupid but I would like to have a confirmation of my thoughts...

I want to develop a web app for smartphones with also a desktop website with the same functionnalities. I will begin to develop the website because I'm more familiar with this. I would like to know if I can also use Sencha Touch for the website...

Or have I to develop the website as a normal website with Gumby or Bootstrap for example and then develop the web app with Sencha ?

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are ok with the limitation of the app running only in webkit browsers there is nothing wrong with building a desktop friendly app with Touch. Be sure to check the docs for Ext.is, there you can find all the tests for the platform the app is running in so you can potentially present variations on the UI and app functionality depending on the environment the app is running in (desktop vs mobile, etc)